# Create object of subclass by object of superclass [python]

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

there is way (in python) to create subclass obj by superclass obj?
I have to parse a file so I have to:

1. open file and parse => superclass obj
2. try to extend file if conditions are good => subclass obj

Having to create SuperClass obj before checking it,
I already have a potential obj of SubClass (no need to parse file again)

es:

```
class SupClass():
  def __init__(self, filename: str):
    self.file = filename
    
class SubClass(SupClass):
  def __init__(self, filename: str, extra: str):
    super().__init__(filename)
    self.extra = extra
```

But How to do something like:

```
A = SupClass('filepath')
B = SubClass(A, 'extra_input')
```

tankyou.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to write: `B = SubClass(A.file, 'extra_input')`?

Comment: No, i want B= SubClass(<A.obj>, 'extra_input')

Answer (score 1):

This is better handled with a class method. `__init__` should be the "simplest" way to initialize your class; extra logic (like extracting a filename from somewhere else) should be delegated.

```
class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, extra: str):
        super().__init__(str)
        self.extra = extra

    @classmethod
    def from_sup_class(cls, x: SupClass, extra: str):
        return cls(x.filename, extra)

A = SupClass('filepath')
B = SubClass.from_sup_class(A, 'extra')
```

Alternately, instead of each subclass having to duplicate a similar method tailored to its own extra arguments, the superclass itself can provide a method that will accept arbitrary arguments and pass them on to subclass.

```
class SupClass():
    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        self.file = filename

    @classmethod
    def from_sup_class(cls, x: SupClass, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls(x.filename, *args, **kwargs)
    

class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, extra: str):
      super().__init__(filename)
      self.extra = extra

A = SupClass('filepath')
B = SubClass.from_sub_class(A, 'extra')
```

There is no difference from the perspective of the caller; an inherited class method invoked by the subclass still passes the subclass as the first argument.

---

In either case, you probably don't want to duplicate the `filename` parameter in each subclass. Follow the advice from  https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/:

```
class SupClass:
    def __init__(self, *, filename: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filename = filename

    @classmethod
    def from_sup_class(cls, x: 'SupClass', *args, **kwargs):
        return cls(filename=x.filename, *args, **kwargs)


class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, *, extra: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.extra = extra


A = SupClass(filename='filename')
B = SubClass.from_sup_class(A, extra='extra')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the SubClass constructor to accept an instance of SupClass and extract the necessary information from it.

```
class SupClass:
    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        self.file = filename

class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, super_instance: SupClass, extra: str):
        super().__init__(super_instance.file)
        self.extra = extra


A = SupClass('filepath')
B = SubClass(A, 'extra_input')
```

Comment: But now you *must* have a superclass instance before you can instantiate the subclass.

Comment: But here subclass instance parse again file as superclass.. I think.. (i have already sup-obj)

Comment: @petuniarose, currently accepted answer is exactly copied answer from this, line by line. Is there any specific reason for accepting that and rejecting this?

Comment: Tank you @TheHungryCub, I understtod better the main point in the other answer, because the point is i cannot directly convert an instance of a superclass into an instance of a subclass. but your answer is a great help for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a default value for extra:

```
class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, extra: str = None):
        super().__init__(filename)
        self.extra = extra
```

Comment: Python doesn't allow method overloading.

Comment: However is not my case. I already have Superclass object, and I'm trying to not parse again from file, only to extend previous object